# Wordpress.org: Having trouble changing background

Tags: wordpress, colors, background

I have a wordpress theme and in the options panel that it came with I can change the background to various textures but I would like to override that and change it to white.

In my CSS I think [this is](http://postimage.org/image/pvou4epz3/) (screenshot) where the background is but I've tried playing around with it and it continually comes up with the same texture.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To change your background image/color, you need to change the css line where it says:

```
html, body { background: url(.../admin/images/bg_texture.jpg) fixed repeat; height: 100%;  }
```

The url() part is linking to the image which is your background texture. If you just want a white background texture, then delete the url part and replace with something like this:

```
html, body { background: #fff; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Ok I have that a shot but unfortunately it still comes up as the background texture.

Comment: In the theme's options I have the option to: "Quickly add CSS markup to your theme by adding it here. This will override any other styles. E.g: #mycssid { color: #757575; }"